# How to check which SilverStripe CMS and Framework is running (Besides hovering over logo in admin view)?

Tags: composer-php, silverstripe

I just recently upgraded a SilverStripe 3.0.5 site to the latest version (3.1.6, I'm guessing) using Composer. I went into the admin view and hovered over the SilverStripe logo and I see this message: Version: Framework: Unknown, CMS: 3.0.5

But this can't be correct because, judging from how the admin view looks, it's NOT SilverStripe 3.0.5 anymore. I looked at the silverstripe_version file under the cms folder and it says 3.0.5. Changing that to be whatever seems to affect what is shown when hovering over the SilverStripe logo in admin view.

What is another way to confirm the version of SilverStripe installed? Is there a more concrete way to tell besides just looking at how the admin view looks?

This is what my composer.json file looks like, for reference:

```
{
    "name": "silverstripe/installer",
    "description": "The SilverStripe Framework Installer",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.2",
        "silverstripe/cms": "3.1.*",
        "silverstripe/framework": "3.1.*",
        "silverstripe-themes/simple": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "silverstripe/compass": "*",
        "silverstripe/docsviewer": "*"
    },

    "require": {
    "monolog/monolog": "1.0.*"
    },

    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to control the version with composer, but otherwise check the `docs/en/04_changelogs` or similar directory as it changed from 3.0.x to 3.1.x. You'll be able to see the different version change logs so that might help a bit.

The latest stable version of SilverStripe is 3.1.15 and 3.2.0-rc1 is also available. I would check your composer requirements as that would be what is driving the version.

Comment: I added my composer.json file to my post...I noticed when I clicked on the help link in the admin view, I was taken to the SilverStripe 3.2 API docs. I don't understand how that's possible. I  also saw a 3.2.0 log file in frameworks/docs/en/04_changelogs....How did I upgrade to 3.2 when I specified 3.1 in the composer.json file?

Comment: That's odd, I know the 3.2.0 log file is in the 3 branch. Have you tried setting the cms/framework versions to `3.1.15` in your composer.json and see if that works? I'm not sure how it would grab 3.2 with your current settings.

Comment: I tried setting the cms and framework versions to 3.1.15 in the composer.json file, but when I ran composer update, nothing happened. It said "nothing to install or update." No errors were shown, and the SilverStripe site is still running 3.0.5.

Answer (score 0):

On shell you can run

```
composer info -i
```

which outputs all installed packages with the currently installed version.

You can also filter for silverstripe packages, e.g.

```
composer info -i | grep silverstripe
```